# Writing the Windows Event Log using Visual Studio C++ 6

Tags: visual-c++, event-log

I am attempting to write a simple function using VC++6 to write to the event log. It must be in this version of studio because it is being added to a legacy application. The problem that I am having is that it writes the message similar to below. The only thing that is valid here is the "This is a test" string. I don't need this to be very complicated. I just need to be able to write to the event log for a specific application. Any thoughts? I have seen a few articles but they appear to be a lot more than I need.

The description for Event ID 3 from source Application cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

This is a test

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

Answer (score 0):

It's been a very long time, but I seem to remember that you might need to create a *Message Resource Dll" to fix this. Or at least have some message resources somewhere.

This article seems like it might be able to help (and it support VC6): [Using MC.exe, message resources and the NT event log in your own projects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mctutorial.aspx?fid=15526&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26)

Comment: I am still playing with this using the link provided. Even with the message DLL, I am still getting the error that it can't find the resource. I plan on trying this again next week and hopefully I will come back with good news. Thanks.